# Usuário Logado aparecer no Form Principal C#

Tags: c#

Boa tarde!!!

Estou com um problema que não sei o porquê... Eu tenho um programa em um Windows Forms C#. Tem uma janela de Login que entra numa janela Principal. Eu uso o mesmo principio de armazenar a sessão do usuário logado e buscar durante o aplicativo rodando. E funciona pois armazena esse usuário no banco de dados a qualquer momento que eu executo a função. Mas se eu peço para mostrar esse usuário em uma label ou textbox na janela, ela não aparece!!! E o interessante é que se eu coloco um botão na janela principal para abrir um formulário filho e coloco exatamente o MESMO CÓDIGO no formulário filho, o dito cujo do usuário aparece... É como se no formulário principal não permitisse isso... Alguém sabe me dizer aonde estou errando?

"Classe Login"

```
public class LoginSenha

{
    public static string AUsuario = "";
    public static string ANOME = "";
}
```

"Form Login" - evento click pra logar

```
private void btnAcessar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
        {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=R:\Projetos\Unilever\Software\DataBase_Knorr.accdb";
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Usuario, SENHA FROM USUARIOS WHERE Usuario='" + lblUser.Text + "'and SENHA='" + txtSenha.Text + "'", con);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            frm_Fabrima frl = new frm_Fabrima();
            frl.Show();
            this.Visible = false;

            LoginSenha.AUsuario = lblUser.Text;
            LoginSenha.ANOME = lblNOME.Text;

            usuarioConectado = lblUser.Text;

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Usuário/Senha Incorretos");
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

"Form Principal"

...No Form_Load...

```
 private void frm_Fabrima_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        inicializar();

        CarregaSKU();

        txtOrdemProducao.Focus();

        cbSKU.Text = "";

        lblConectado.Text = frm_Login.usuarioConectado;

        lblConectado.Text = LoginSenha.ANOME.ToString();

        rbBartelt1.Checked = true;
    }
```

Pelo que viu, eu tentei duas formas de tentar buscar e mesmo assim não consigo

Comment: Coloque a parte toda do seu fonte, referente a cada trecho que você já informou na sua pergunta... Com o que você nos informou, não da para te ajudar em muita coisa. Acredito que você não esteja passando o objeto corretamente entre as telas, mas só com você nos informando o resto do fonte da para confirmar isto.

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado pela ajuda... Alterei o post, vê se fica mais compreensivel os códigos

Comment: Beleza, agora deu pra ver legal, não posso dar uma resposta detalhada porque o Moderator marcou sua pergunta como **pendente**, mas você precisa instanciar a classe `LoginSenha` no seu form de Login e passar ele no constructor da sua tela principal `frm_Fabrima frl = new frm_Fabrima(dadosLogin);`

Comment: Defina a class LoginSenha como static

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro Eu tentei essas alterações e ainda assim não funciona. Agora é estranho que mesmo não instanciando a classe e passando no constructor, pq ele aparece em qualquer formulário filho que eu crio, menos no principal? Deve ser alguma propriedade do formulário pai que tenho que mudar... Vamos esperar liberar o post para comunicar melhor